# How to use let-values in Gambit Scheme?

Tags: scheme, gambit

I'm testing if redefining of variables work in Scheme, tested this code in Gambit:

```lisp
(let-values ((x (values 1 2 3))
             (x (values 4 5 6)))
  (display x)
  (newline))
```

To see what will be the output. But Gambit throws an error:

> Unbound variable: let-values

But I've checked the source and let-values is implemented. How to use this name in Gambit. It's probably related to libraries but I don't know how to use them in Gabmit.

I've tried:

```lisp
(import gambit)
```

But got an error:

> Unbound variable: import

I'm executing gambit with `gsi file.scm`

Comment: This is a `let-values` form: `(let-values ([(x y) (values 1 2)]) (display x))`

Comment: @mnemenaut according to R7RS specification let-values can accept symbols that will contain a list of values the same as with lambda. The implementation from R7RS works this way. `(let-values ([x (values 1 2)]) (display x))` is a valid syntax

Comment: which version of gambit are you using? Error is reported as  `duplicate variable in bindings` in 4.9.5

Comment: @rajashekar version `Gambit v4.9.3` provided. I got an error about missing `let-values` like it doesn't include the R7RS library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gambit 4.9.5:

```lisp
> (let-values ((x (values 1 2 3))
             (x (values 4 5 6)))
  (display x)
  (newline))
*** ERROR IN (stdin)@5.15 -- Duplicate variable in bindings
```

It doesn't let you re-use identifiers in the bindings; R7RS says of `let-values` that

> It is an error for a variable to appear more than once in the set of `<formals>`.

Fix that, and it works:

```lisp
> (let-values ((x (values 1 2 3))
             (y (values 4 5 6)))
  (display x)
  (newline))
(1 2 3)
```

---

After doing some digging through git commit history, it looks like gambit added `let-values` in April 2019, and the 4.9.3 you are using was released in February 2019. So using too old a version is responsible for the error you're getting about it not being defined/bound. If you'd been using a more recent instance you'd have run into the error addressed in the first part of this answer.

Comment: How do you execute gambit? I don't get an error about Duplicate variable in bindings only about missing `let-values`. I use version `v4.9.3` did macro `let-values` appear in a minor bugfix release?

Comment: @jcubic With `gsi`. I assume `let-values` has been supported by it for ages; even in non-R7RS schemes (I have no idea if it's in R6RS) it's a common thing to have.

Comment: Hmm. It appears to [have been committed](https://github.com/gambit/gambit/commit/543c5b174c0b453f4d2d5d8f8f6d61b09423dfce) in April 2019 (More recently than I'd figured) and it looks like 4.9.3 is from February 2019.

Comment: Thanks for checking that out, it seems that the Fedora package is really outdated then. I will try to install it from source.